# Разделение строки на число и символы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например, есть строка `5min`, как можно разделить ее на подстроки `5` и `min` в Python 3, желательно не прибегая к регулярным выражениям?

Comment: У вас там всегда min или может быть любая строка?

Comment: @LinnTroll, строки будут разные. Например `1y`, `2w` или `14d`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> def my_split(s):
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if not c.isdigit():
            return s[:i], s[i:]

>>> my_split("123asdf")
('123', 'asdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

Регулярные выражения вполне подходят для данной задачи:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

def diff2seconds(time_diff_string, unit2seconds={'min': 60, 'd': 86400}):
    n, unit = re.match(r"(\d+)(min|y|w|d)$", time_diff_string).groups()
    return int(n) * unit2seconds[unit]

print(diff2seconds('5min')) 
# -> 300
```